# Xamarin Forms - Singleton with a List

Tags: c#, xamarin

Can somebody help me implement a singleton with a list from Carting module.

**My error**:
*'Cart' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and the best extension method overload 'SettersExtensions.Add(IList, BindableProperty, object)' requires a receiver of type 'IList'*

here's what i have for now

**Cart.cs**

```
public sealed class Cart
    {
        public static Cart Instance { get; } = new Cart();

        static Cart() { } 
        private Cart() { }

        public void GetAddedMeals()
        {

        }
    }
```

**QuantityPopUp.xaml.cs**

```
private void btnOK_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Cart.Instance.Add(tempcodeofmenu, int.Parse(entQuantity.Text));


            Navigation.PushAsync(new OrderCart());



        }
```

**OrderCart.cs**

```
  public OrderCart ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

          MyCart.ItemsSource = Cart.Instance.GetAddedMeals();
        }
```

Comment: `public void GetAddedMeals()` returns nothing...  this cannot be implemented: `MyCart.ItemsSource = Cart.Instance.GetAddedMeals();`

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this code, it really makes no sense. Why do you think that you can call `Add` on your instance of `Cart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something from:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourItemClass> GetAddedMeals()
{
    ... // Fill in the blanks according to your implementation. Return a collection.
}
```

An ObservableCollection can be useful as a source for your list for monitoring changes to that list.

And then you need to allow this to be added to. Perhaps you meant `Cart` to have a collection as a base class? That way an "Add" may be implemented that way?

```
public Cart : ObservableCollection<YourItemClass>
```

But considering your question I'd avoid that for now and go straight for your Cart class owning an ObservableCollection as a member:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourItemClass> myCollection;
```

And implement your own Add class:

```
public void Add(YourItemClass item)
{
    myCollection.Add(item);
}
```